# Major Issue with Blackberry SDK - UI Trips out

Tags: java, blackberry, user-interface, interface, java-me

I have the following problem.

I have a browser field embedded in a manager.
Sometimes upon selecting items in a drop down list the following happens.

Step : 1 - Original Page [image]

Step : 2 Choosing from  a drop down.

[image]

Step : 3 Selecting the item!- Interface trips out. with a write patch after you make a selection. It moves down a bit.

[image]

Also the pointer extents beyond the manage that it is contained it. Causing custom buttons no to work.
As shown below:

[image]

Any one had same issue? Please help...